# Two result sets when using exec in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, see below, that execute.  In the stored procedure is the exec command.  When I execute the stored procedure, I am getting two result sets, the results from my exec command and then a return value.  How do I get just the results from my exec command?

```
DECLARE @openquery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tsql   NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @linkedserver NVARCHAR(10)

SET @linkedserver = 'orad'
SET @openquery = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linkedserver + ','''

SET @tsql = 'SELECT 
            COUNT(empl_id) AS emplcnt 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    empl_id,
                    empl_last_nm,
                    empl_first_nm,
                    empl_middle_init,
                    empl_pay_plan_cd,
                    empl_stat,
                    empl_typ,
                    empl_cctr_id,
                    empl_corporate_id,
                    empl_dir_chrg_ind,
                    LEVEL 
                FROM 
                    cdas.vdwhemp3 
                WHERE 
                    empl_stat in (''''ACTIVE    '''',''''DISABLED  '''',''''LEAVE     '''',''''MILITARY  '''',''''SALARY CON'''',''''UNKNOWN   '''') 
                START WITH 
                    empl_id = '''''+ @id + '''''
                CONNECT BY PRIOR 
                    empl_id = empl_empl_id 
                ORDER SIBLINGS BY 
                    empl_last_nm
            )'')'

EXEC (@openquery+@tsql)
```

Comment: How are you executing the stored proc? SSMS Execute... dialog adds code to store & return the return code, you can avoid this by removing the `SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value` part.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am doing.  So if i run it from my program it will just return the data i need.  Thank you.